# Adding new item as SQL Database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to add and SQL Server Database in Visual Studios. I am in the solutions explorer, click on the folder -> add new item -> then SQL Server Database System should be an option but isn't. How can I fix this? I have already downloaded the SQL tools to Visual Studios.

I have already downloaded the SQL tools to Visual Studios and restarted the program

Comment: Propably what you are looking for is the following: View -> SQL Server Object Exporer -> Add SQL Server (DB icon with the plus on it)